# How to set a generic property attribute in a generic method when use it?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I create a generic method:

```
private void UpdateAllProperties<idType, entityType>(entityType currentEntity, entityType newEntity)
    where idType : IEquatable<idType>
    where entityType : AbstractEntity<idType>
{
    var currentEntityProperties = currentEntity.GetType().GetProperties();
    var newEntityProperties = newEntity.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var currentEntityProperty in currentEntityProperties)
    {
        foreach (var newEntityProperty in newEntityProperties)
        {
            if (newEntityProperty.Name == currentEntityProperty.Name)
            {
                if (currentEntityProperty.PropertyType == typeof(AbstractEntity<>))
                {
                    // Here i want to use this method again, but i need to inform the types.. how can i do anything like that:
                    var idPropertyType = currentEntityProperty.PropertyType.GetProperty("Id").GetType();
                    var entityPropertyType = currentEntityProperty.PropertyType;

                    // Here i got the error because i cannot set through this way
                    this.UpdateAllProperties<idPropertyType, entityPropertyType>(currentEntityProperty.GetValue(currentEntity, null), newEntityProperty.GetValue(newEntity, null));

                    break;
                }
                else if (currentEntityProperty.PropertyType == typeof(ICollection<>))
                {
                    // TODO

                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    currentEntityProperty.SetValue(currentEntity, newEntityProperty.GetValue(newEntity, null), null);

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to make the call using `Type.GetMethod()` to get the method and `MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod()` to set it up with the right types, before using `MethodInfo.Invoke()` to call the method.

Something like:

```
var idPropertyType = currentEntityProperty.PropertyType.GetProperty("Id").PropertyType;
var entityPropertyType = currentEntityProperty.PropertyType;

var method = this.GetType().GetMethod("UpdateAllProperties", 
                              BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(idPropertyType, entityPropertyType);
genericMethod.Invoke(this, new[] { 
    currentEntityProperty.GetValue(currentEntity, null),   
    newEntityProperty.GetValue(newEntity, null)
});
```

Comment: I got a problem in this line: `var idPropertyType = currentEntityProperty.PropertyType.GetProperty("Id").GetType();` because the returned type is a `RuntimePropertyInfo`, not a `int` or `decimal` (if i have declared the type of the AbstractEntity Id as a `int` or `decimal`), so how can i get the type `int` or `decimal` instead `RuntimePropertyInfo`?

Comment: I think you wanted: `var idPropertyType = currentEntityProperty.PropertyType.GetProperty("Id").PropertyType`

Comment: Yes, it's that! Let me test if everthing is ok now.